# Spring: Is it possible to have a duplicate constructor with different qualifier while autowiring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired

I am trying to autowire a member in a class using the constructor.

```
@Component
public class MyClass {
    private ClassA myMember;

    @Autowire
    public MyClass(ClassA objectA) {

       myMember = objectA;
    }
}
```

If I have multiple sources that create beans of ClassA, is it possible to have a duplicate constructor definition that instantiates based on the bean that was autowired into this class?

I want to do something like this:

```
    @Component
    public class MyClass {
        private ClassA myMember;

        @Autowire
        public MyClass(@Qualifier ("qualifierA") ClassA objectA) {

           myMember = objectA;
        }

        @Autowire
        public MyClass(@Qualifier ("qualifierB") ClassA objectB) {

           myMember = objectB;
        }
    }
```

I tried using `@Qualifier` this way, but it didn't work. 
Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do, with Spring? How can I disambiguate based on the name (`qualifierA`) or (`qualifierB`), if the bean definition is like:

```
@Bean (name = "qualifierA")
public ClassA getQualifierA() {
    ...
}

@Bean (name = "qualifierB")
public ClassA getQualifierB() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried annotating `@Autowired @Qualifier ("qualifierA")` and `@Autowired @Qualifier ("qualifierB")`?

Comment: Yes, but that didn't work either.

Comment: why are you trying to autowire one field with two different constructors? How can one field have two different values?

Comment: Maybe you just want to use `@Profile`s but don't know they exist? Impossible to tell without knowing your actual use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two constructors with the exact same signature in a single class in Java. Nor any other programming language I've ever encountered. You might use method-injection instead, with two methods (named differently, of course), mark them as `@Autowired(required = false)` and use the proper `@Qualifier(...)` to specify the instance you want to inject. You might want to handle the case when both instances are present in the spring context, so no unexpected things happen.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: no, that is not possible. In Java you cannot have two constructors with exactly the same signature. And also, you can assign only one value to your "myMember".

However, what are you trying to accomplish here? It seems that in some occasions MyClass needs to use "objectA" and in other occasions, you need "objectB".
For these scenarios, you should not use autowiring (you can't), but simply use explicit wiring:

```
@Bean
MyClass myObject() {
   return new MyClass(qualifierA());
}
```